# How to retrieve a data from each row and column from a database in Java

Tags: java

im newbie on Java.
How can i retrieve a data from database and put it on some variable. I have think about array, but the data is in various type. And also the retrieve of data is using a method from another class.

i got a hint to use ArrayList but i dont have any idea to use that. Any clue or advice for me?

This is the main method:

```
class JavaAppsTes {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Database app = new Database();

      /* I don't know what to do here */
   }
```

This is the database class:

```
public void getMenu() {
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER by id_kategori";
    String nama, gambar;
    int id_menu, id_kategori, harga, persediaan;
    int count = 0;

    try (Connection conn = connect(); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet cartRslt = stmt.executeQuery(SQL)) {
        while(cartRslt.next()) {
            id_menu = cartRslt.getInt("id_menu");
            id_kategori = cartRslt.getInt("id_kategori");
            harga = cartRslt.getInt("harga");
            persediaan = cartRslt.getInt("persediaan");
            nama = cartRslt.getString("nama");
            gambar = cartRslt.getString("gambar"); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can i put those data into something, so the front end can use the retrieved data?

By the way, since i got the clue about ArrayList i created some menu class like this:

```
public class Menu {
    private int id_menu;
    private int id_kategori;
    private String nama;
    private int harga;
    private int persediaan;
    private String gambar;

    public Menu(int id_menu, int id_kategori, String nama, int harga, int persediaan, String gambar) {
        this.id_menu = id_menu;
        this.id_kategori = id_kategori;
        this.nama = nama;
        this.harga = harga;
        this.persediaan = persediaan;
        this.gambar = gambar;
    }

    public int getid_menu(){
       return id_kategori;
    }

    public void setid_menu(int id_menu){
        this.id_menu = id_menu;
    }

    public int getid_kategori(){
       return id_kategori;
    }

    public void setid_kategori(int id_kategori){
        this.id_kategori = id_kategori;
    }

    public String getnama(){
        return nama;
    }

    public void setnama(String nama){
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public int getharga(){
        return harga;
    }

    public void setharga(int harga){
        this.harga = harga;
    }

    public int getpersediaan(){
        return persediaan;
    }

    public void setpersediaan(int persediaan){
        this.persediaan = persediaan;
    }

    public String getgambar(){
        return gambar;
    }

    public void setgambar(String gambar){
        this.gambar = gambar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need ArrayList define it before loop, add each menu and return it after.

```
public ArrayList<Menu> getMenu() {
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER by id_kategori";
String nama, gambar;
int id_menu, id_kategori, harga, persediaan;
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Menu> arr = new ArrayList<>();
try (Connection conn = connect(); 
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
ResultSet cartRslt = stmt.executeQuery(SQL)) {
    while(cartRslt.next()) {
        id_menu = cartRslt.getInt("id_menu");
        id_kategori = cartRslt.getInt("id_kategori");
        harga = cartRslt.getInt("harga");
        persediaan = cartRslt.getInt("persediaan");
        nama = cartRslt.getString("nama");
        gambar = cartRslt.getString("gambar"); 
       arr.add(new Menu(id_menu, id_kategori, nama, harga, persediaan, gambar));
 }
 }
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a JSON array, where every entry is a JSON object having key value pairs for the columns and values in each record of your result set:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray ();
try (Connection conn = connect(); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet cartRslt = stmt.executeQuery(SQL)) {
    while(cartRslt.next()) {
        JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
        id_menu = cartRslt.getInt("id_menu");
        id_kategori = cartRslt.getInt("id_kategori");
        harga = cartRslt.getInt("harga");
        persediaan = cartRslt.getInt("persediaan");
        nama = cartRslt.getString("nama");
        gambar = cartRslt.getString("gambar");

        row.put("id_menu", String.valueOf(id_menu));
        row.put("id_kategori", String.valueOf(id_kategori));
        row.put("harga", String.valueOf(harga));
        row.put("persediaan", String.valueOf(persediaan));
        row.put("nama", nama);
        row.put("gambar", gambar);
        json.put(row);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Then, later in your code, you can simply deliver this JSON string to your UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

To use an array list you should change the signature of your method from void to `List<Menu>`. That way you can return a list with all of your menu objects.

```
public List<Menu> getMenu() {
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER by id_kategori";
    String nama, gambar;
    int id_menu, id_kategori, harga, persediaan;
    int count = 0;
    List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection conn = connect(); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet cartRslt = stmt.executeQuery(SQL)) {
        while(cartRslt.next()) {
            id_menu = cartRslt.getInt("id_menu");
            id_kategori = cartRslt.getInt("id_kategori");
            harga = cartRslt.getInt("harga");
            persediaan = cartRslt.getInt("persediaan");
            nama = cartRslt.getString("nama");
            gambar = cartRslt.getString("gambar"); 
            menus.add(new Menu(id_menu, id_kategori, ...));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
return menus
}
```

As far as displaying for a user, you'll need to decide on a web framework or gui.